# Append a code when at the current page in wp_list_pages()

Tags: hooks, walker, child-pages, wp-list-pages

I'm using `wp_list_pages()` to show pages and subpages in a tree view and I need to add a "read more" as a sub-item right after the current page.

Example:

We are at the "Page tree"

- Page one
- Page two
- **Page tree** 
  **READ MORE**
- Page four
- Page five

I'm not sure if this is achieved with hooks or walker, any suggestion would be appreciate!

Code I'm using:

```
function dkc_list_subpgm() { 

global $post; 

if (is_singular('pgm') && $post->post_parent )  
      $childpages = 
      wp_list_pages(  array(
      'post_type' => 'pgm',
      'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
      'title_li' => '',
      'child_of' => $post->post_parent ,
      'echo' =>'0'            
        ));
else
      $childpages = 
      wp_list_pages(  array(
      'post_type' => 'pgm',
      'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
      'title_li' => '',
      'child_of' => $post->ID,
      'echo' =>'0' 
        ));

if ( $childpages ) {

$string = '<ul class="wpb_page_list">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('dkc_childpages', 'dkc_list_subpgm');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a custom walker and then extend the [`Walker_Page::start_el()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_page/start_el/), like so:

```php
// Based on Walker_Page for WordPress v6.0
// @link https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0/src/wp-includes/class-walker-page.php#L105-L219

class My_Walker_Page extends Walker_Page {
    public function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        /* This checks if the current page in the list is the current page you're on.
         * - $current_object_id is the ID of the current page you're on
         * - $data_object->ID is the ID of the current page in the list
         */
        $is_current_page = ( (int) $current_object_id === (int) $data_object->ID );

        // This one adds the "read more" inside the link, i.e. before the </a> tag.
        if ( $is_current_page ) {
            $args['link_after'] .= ' READ MORE 1 (inside "a")';
        }

        // Call the parent method to build the (complete) <li ...><a ...>...</a> part.
        parent::start_el( $output, $data_object, $depth, $args, $current_object_id );

        // This one adds the "read more" outside the link, i.e. after the </a> tag,
        // but still inside the same or current LI element.
        if ( $is_current_page ) {
            $output .= ' READ MORE 2 (outside "a")';
        }
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- You could instead use a conditional tag such as `is_page( $data_object->ID )` or `is_single( $data_object->ID )`, but using the above `(int) $current_object_id === (int) $data_object->ID` is easier because it *works regardless the post type*.
- Just choose one of the `if ( $is_current_page ) { ... }` blocks above, or use both if you want to.. :)

And then pass an instance of the above class to [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) (via the `walker` argument), e.g.

```php
// NOTE: It's up to you on how to load the PHP FILE which defines the My_Walker_Page
// class, but for example, require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/class-my-walker-page.php';

wp_list_pages( array(
    'walker' => new My_Walker_Page(),
) );
```

#### Additional Notes

- Your `dkc_list_subpgm()` code could be simplified like so where I used just one `wp_list_pages()` instead of two:

  ```php
  function dkc_list_subpgm() {

      global $post;

      $child_of = $post->ID;
      if ( is_singular( 'pgm' ) && $post->post_parent ) {
          $child_of = $post->post_parent;
      }

      $childpages = wp_list_pages( array(
          'post_type'   => 'pgm',
          'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
          'title_li'    => '',
          'child_of'    => $child_of,
          'echo'        => 0, // just use 0 (without quotes) and not '0'
          'walker'      => new My_Walker_Page(),
      ) );

      if ( $childpages ) {
          return '<ul class="wpb_page_list">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
      }

      return '';

  }
  ```

Comment: Hi there, almost worked, I'm using a post type (pgm) and tried to use is_singular but with no luck, also the page list now is showing a title "Pages" that it doesn't go away with title_li='' any ideas? 
I tried if ( is_singular('pgm') && $current_object_id = 0 )

Comment: Thanks for adding your full code to the question ( although you should've notified me.. =) ), but I edited it and removed the `'walker' => new My_Walker_Page(),` part (so that my answer would be "valid"..). So please try the revised `My_Walker_Page` code in my answer, and let me know if it works now for you? (and you can also try the simplified `dkc_list_subpgm` function code..)